# Does the value of $TMPDIR ever change automatically? If so, why?

Tags: macos

On my Mac, `$TMPDIR` resolves as follows:

```
➜ ~ echo $TMPDIR
/var/folders/v_/psqnv77d4nvcpjrr_3jz4tw40000gp/T/
```

That looks to me like a randomly generated path, and some Googling confirms -- other people have different random strings on their machines.

What I'm wondering is this: when does this value get generated? Once generated, does it persist for the life of the machine, or does the system ever generated a new value? If it gets regenerated, what happens to the contents at the previous location? If there are multiple users on the machine, does each have their own value for $TMPDIR?

(I'm separately led to believe that the contents of the directory are [removed at a per-file level if the file in question has not been accessed in three days](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/71382), which leads me to guess that, if a regeneration event did occur, recently accessed files might be moved/copied into the new directory.)

If it does change, what value do we get from that? I assume there's some kind of security benefit that would prompt Apple to build this mechanism. (I can see how multiple users sharing a TMPDIR could be problematic; are there other threats?)

Comment: I found this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/555214 about TMPDIR format, but I can't confirm. I checked https://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-431/dirhelper.tproj/dirhelper.c.auto.html and it looks like it uses __user_local_dirname, but I can't find its implementation

Comment: Let’s edit this down to one question, the main one needing answered. Once you are that key piece answered, please ask as many linked follow on questions as needed.

Comment: If you make a second user on your Mac, you can gather empirical evidence on whether they collide with `su - newuser`

Comment: A [side question on when /private/var/folders gets culled](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/71382?answerId=207917022#207917022) would be an excellent side question for now. Used to be any file not accessed for three days was culled in a daily clean up script, but I haven’t tested that lately…